# JAVA Regex for matching 1 or more occurrences

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the start and end index for a particular substring.

Input String: somerandoMMMstring

My ultimate goal is to get the start and end index of the MMM pattern in this example, but ultimately, any number of consecutive M's.

My regex pattern is: `.*(M+).*`

For some reason, group 1 is producing the String `M`.

How can I refactor my grouping or regex to be able to get the entire `MMM` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the non-greedy variant of `*` => `*?`

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(M+).*?");
final String string = "somerandoMMMstring";
final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

> MMM

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Matcher` API for this:

```
String str = "somerandoMMMstring";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("M+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.err.printf("match: %s, start: %d, end: %d%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
}
```

**Output:**

```
match: MMM, start: 9, end: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `.*[^M](M+)[^M].*`